# Cant get value from input

Tags: angularjs

I am using ui-router, and have a state like this;

```
.state('add', {
            url: '/add',
            views: {
                "list@home.main": {
                    templateUrl: 'add.html',
                    controller: "AddController",
                    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
                }
            }

        })
```

in my template i have this;

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.product.title" name="title" required>
```

In my controller i want to get the value, from the input field.

```
myApp.controller('myController', function myController($scope, $rootScope, Incident, $state, $stateParams) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.product = new Product();

    var myValue = vm.product.title;
});
```

But myValue is always empty. What am i missing?

(the Product() is;)

```
myApp.factory('Product', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://api.com/api/products/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code, specifically your html and controller code? You're creating a binding to the scope by using `ng-model`, but I can't see where you're declaring any scope variables.

Comment: I updated the question with my controller - makes any sence?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to accomplish, if you want to load product from backend and then inspect title then:

`Product` is a resource. You should use it like `Product.get({ id: 3 })` to get actual product - product will be returned as promise so you may then use `product.$promise.then(...)` or just assign it to a variable (angularjs will be smart enough to do binding from promise):

```
Product.get({id:123})
    .$promise.then(function(product) {
      $scope.product = product;
      // product.title should be usable here
    });
```

Resources are complex topic, one tutorial here: https://devdactic.com/improving-rest-with-ngresource/

If you want to read product.title on client side then you are doing it too early. 
If you are using `form` then bind to submit event using `ngSubmit` and inside handler read `product.title` value. If you access that variable in controller constructor, user doesn't have chance to change anything so it must be empty. If you want to monitor `product.title` changes constantly use `ng-change` directive on input or `$watch(product.title, function() { })` but I think in your case `ng-submit` will be enough.